# How to sign in Outlook app?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I can sign in Outlook web with my name and password but I can't sign in Outlook app on laptop with the same name and password. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Desktop Outlook setup is in Control Panel, Mail . Check the settings there. In most cases, Desktop Outlook works once you have logged into Windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean adding your Outlook.com account to Outlook desktop    client?

If so, how did you add your account? And have you receive any    error?

In addition, what's the version of your Outlook? (File >    Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

Please try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.